# Parsing error; Unexpected token index in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have created a javascript that has a parsing error for unexpected token index.   I have reviewed the code many times and can not find out what I have excluded from the coding.  Can some one assist with recommendation on what I've done incorrectly.

```
ddListeners=function(){

var items = document.getElementsByClassName("image");

//getting img elements by CSS class name to register event

for(let index = 0; index < items.length;index++);

{
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The code you have posted is not sufficient to reproduce the problem. Please show us more of your code.

Comment: It's not the reason for the error, but you probably don't want `;` at the end of the `for` line.

Comment: Please update your question with proper code examples and add more details.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want `getElementsByClassName` vs `getElementByTagName`?

If you want `getElementsByClassName` you want to make sure you have the class on your tags

examples

```
<img class="image" src="www.something.com/myimage.jpg"/>
<div class="image"> some data or more elements</div>
```

To confirm you have elements with that class you can open the console in your browser and try running `document.getElementsByClassName("image").length)` this should be > 0

If it is, try adding a debugger in your code and keeping the console open and running the command again, you can also alert or console out the count.

```
dListeners=function(){
  var items = document.getElementsByClassName("image");
  alert(items.length); //for testing, this should be greater than 0

  //getting img elements by CSS class name to register event
  for(let index = 0; index < items.length;index++){ ... }
}
```

If you were getting results before, when running in the conosle, and are now getting a 0, its because you are running your function before the DOM has loaded.

Make sure what ever is calling `dListener` is called after the DOM loads

Here is a quick working demo if you want to compare: https://jsfiddle.net/v7g8r2w4/